# Loop CSV and post data through REST API

Tags: api, powershell, loops, csv, foreach

I have simple CSV file like:

```
device,template
dlinkrouter,DLink DGS Switch
cisco, DLink DGS Switch
```

And simple script like below:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\m.zurek\Desktop\devices.csv"

$csv.device | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_
    $action = "http://localhost:8090/api/json/ncmsettings/addDevice"
    $hash = @{}
    $hash.Add("apiKey", "cb464d185c0cdf785295a6a0a1d227a2")
    $hash.Add("IPADDRESS", $($_))
    $hash.Add("DEVICE_BEHAVIOUR", "DLink DGS Switch")
    $adddev = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $action -UseBasicParsing -Body $hash -Method Post
    return $adddev
}
```

Problem is that the script adds only the first device from the CSV file. On the rest I have response from API about error. Not sure if it's a problem with API or with my script.

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : 
Content           : {"Message":"Error in adding device. Zip the logs folder and send it to support.","isSuccess":false,"statusMsg":"Failure","bulkResourceIds":[]}

RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 
                Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
                Access-Control-Max-Age: 5000
                Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                Vary: Accept-Encoding
                Content-Type: application/json;c...
Forms             : 
Headers           : {[Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *], [Access-Control-Allow-Methods, GET,POST], [Access-Control-Max-Age, 5000], [Transfer-Encoding, chunked]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : 
RawContentLength  : 144
```

`Write-Host` works fine and write name of all devices from CSV.

Comment: Is this a typo mistake while posting code.. it should be $_ not $ .....
$hash.Add("IPADDRESS",$($_))

Comment: Yes, there is a typo. Should be $_. Edited now.

Comment: Did you "Zip the logs folder and send it to support"? Did you find the log and check it?

Comment: I have send the logs and waiting for response. Didn't find any relevant info in these logs.

Comment: A nickel for every time a web application returns an error with status code 200 ... *\*sigh\**

Comment: Solved. There was a problem wit API, not with my script. Thanks all for trying.